# How to add stats.js to a js file

Tags: javascript

I want to show fps and memory stats in the browser using [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/)

```
.
├── game.js
├── index.html
```

in index.html I have

```
<body>
    <div id="stats"></div>
    <canvas style="z-index: -5;" id="game">
        
    </canvas>
    <script src="game.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

in game.js I have

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/10/Stats.js';


var stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel( 1 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
document.body.appendChild( stats.dom )
```

this throws an error in the console

```
game.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: stats.showPanel is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an old version

Use this instead:

```
import Stats from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/17/Stats.js'
```